# How to implement horizontal scroll in a table cell?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to scroll some text in a table cell but no luck so far. Here is the relevant code:

CSS:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 20px;
}

div.scrollable {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```html
const AtableRow = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <tr>
                <td>Something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div className="scrollable">
                        Something really really long that I wish to be
                        scrollable but aint so I go to StackOverflow for help.
                        Thank you.
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </>
    );
};
const Atable = () => {
    return (
        <div className="column">
            <table name="variation">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Heading</th>
                    </tr>
                    <AtableRow />
                </tbody>
            </table>{" "}
        </div>
    );
};

const Text = () => (
    <div className="column">
        <span>just some text</span>
    </div>
);

const TestTable = () => {
    return (
        <div className="column">
            <div className="row">
                <Atable />
                <Text />
                <Atable />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Picture:
[image]

Modified .scrollable to add:

```
div.scrollable {
...
  max-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

But the result is that the columns are stretched.

[image]

---

P.S. Added a code snippet, but it doesn't really show the columns in the output because of flexbox stacking.

Comment: `td {
  scroll-direction: horizontal;
}`

Comment: You also seem to be confused between `<div>` and table structures. Your question is specifically about table cells but your code features `div` elements. Please edit and clarify what you're actually wanting to do. A div inside a table cell is probably **not** what you want. Feels wrong.

Comment: The <div> element is inside a <td> element.  This was suggested in an answer to a similar question elsewhere.  There is no scroll-direction css property for <td> elements.

Comment: Looking at another SO question, I found a partial answer.  On the td containing the div, if I set the maxWidth to 200px, the text appears on one line and is scrollable. 

The weird thing is that any px value under 300 works *and renders identically*, but if I set it to 600px, then I get a result as in the second picture in the OP.

Comment: Table sizing is different from other sizing and can be counter-intuitive. That's why we only use them for tabular data... which this does not appear to be.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I'll think on that. In this case it is used to list similar items that fit in a tabular format. I use tables elsewhere for like data without issue. But I do know that tables are not very flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded, but there are a couple of tricks to know.

The  containing the scrollable div must have a max-width less than the column width, max-width percentages don't seem to work, so use em or px units. Example: `<td style="max-width:30px;">`

The div itself has the following properties:

```css
div.scrollable {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  max-width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

If you want the scrollbar to be visible on a webkit browser such as Chrome, you'll need to deal with pseudo elements:

```css
.scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 7px;
}
.scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
```

Bonus answer:
I wanted to have the scrollbar at the end of the line; to do this add

```css
flex-direction:"row-reverse"
```

to the div properties.

So my html row looks like:

```html
            <tr>
                <td style={{ maxWidth: "1em"}}>
                    <div className="scrollable" style={{flexDirection:"row-reverse", height:"2em"}}>
                        Something really really long that I wish to be
                        scrollable but aint so I go to StackOverflow for help.
                        Thank you.
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>another thing</td>
            </tr>
```